# Slider Range jQuery Uj. Submit value with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have installed on my site the " Slider Range Widget jQuery Uj " you may check documentation here:

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

```
//basic installation is here
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
range: true,
min: 0,
max: 500,
values: [ 75, 300 ],
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
" - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

html

```
<label for="amount">Price range:</label><input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

How to submit the value of "amount" with ajax on change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it inside the `stop()`

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
range: true,
min: 0,
max: 500,
values: [ 75, 300 ],
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
},
stop: function( event, ui ) {
    $.ajax({
                   //do your ajax call here
    });
}
});
```

Hope this helps, thank you